# Ways to count the number of edges in Titan graph

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, titan

I want to count the number of edges in a graph I have loaded into Titan by means of a gremlin script. The graph is pretty small and is supposed to have less than a million edges, but when I try to do the count with `g.E.count()` I get the following error:

> WARN com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx - Query requires iterating over all vertices [()]. For better performance, use indexes.
>
> Permanent exception during backend operation

Stack trace:

```
com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanException: Permanent exception during backend operation at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:65) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.executeRead(BackendTransaction.java:380) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.edgeStoreKeys(BackendTransaction.java:306) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.getVertexIDs(StandardTitanGraph.java:180) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.VertexIterable$1.<init>(VertexIterable.java:31) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.VertexIterable.iterator(VertexIterable.java:29) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.util.VertexCentricEdgeIterable.iterator(VertexCentricEdgeIterable.java:27) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx$5.execute(StandardTitanTx.java:928) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx$5.execute(StandardTitanTx.java:788) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.query.QueryProcessor$LimitAdjustingIterator.getNewIterator(QueryProcessor.java:231) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.query.LimitAdjustingIterator.hasNext(LimitAdjustingIterator.java:32) at
  com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.computeNext(Iterators.java:700) at
  com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143) at
  com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.query.QueryProcessor$OuterIterator.nextInternal(QueryProcessor.java:75) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.query.QueryProcessor$OuterIterator.<init>(QueryProcessor.java:65) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.query.QueryProcessor.iterator(QueryProcessor.java:46) at com.google.common.collect.Iterables$7.iterator(Iterables.java:613) at
  com.tinkerpop.pipes.transform.GraphQueryPipe.processNextStart(GraphQueryPipe.java:49) at
  com.tinkerpop.pipes.transform.GraphQueryPipe.processNextStart(GraphQueryPipe.java:17) at com.tinkerpop.pipes.AbstractPipe.next(AbstractPipe.java:89) at
  com.tinkerpop.pipes.util.Pipeline.next(Pipeline.java:115) at
  com.tinkerpop.pipes.util.PipeHelper.counter(PipeHelper.java:107) at
  com.tinkerpop.gremlin.java.GremlinPipeline.count(GremlinPipeline.java:1534) at
  com.tinkerpop.gremlin.java.GremlinFluentPipeline$count.call(Unknown Source) at
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42) at
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108) at
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112) at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:56) at
  groovysh_evaluate$run.call(Unknown Source) at
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42) at groovysh_evaluate$run.call(Unknown Source) at
  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:67) at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter$evaluate.call(Unknown Source) at
  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:152) at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:114) at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell$leftShift$0.call(Unknown Source) at
  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:88) at
  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at
  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
  org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90) at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233) at
  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1079) at
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128) at
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:148) at
  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:100) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at
  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272) at
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52) at
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:137) at
  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:57) at
  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at
  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
  org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90) at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233) at
  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1079) at
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128) at
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:148) at
  org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:66) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.gremlin.Console.<init>(Console.java:57) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.gremlin.Console.<init>(Console.java:70) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.gremlin.Console.main(Console.java:96)
Caused by:
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.PermanentStorageException: Permanent failure in storage backend at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.berkeleyje.BerkeleyJEKeyValueStore.getSlice(BerkeleyJEKeyValueStore.java:162) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.keyvalue.OrderedKeyValueStoreAdapter.getKeys(OrderedKeyValueStoreAdapter.java:88) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.CachedKeyColumnValueStore.getKeys(CachedKeyColumnValueStore.java:134) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.BackendTransaction$5.call(BackendTransaction.java:309) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.BackendTransaction$5.call(BackendTransaction.java:306) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:62)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentFailureException:
  (JE 5.0.73) JAVA_ERROR: Java Error occurred, recovery may not be possible. at
  com.sleepycat.je.dbi.EnvironmentImpl.checkIfInvalid(EnvironmentImpl.java:1507) at com.sleepycat.je.Database.checkEnv(Database.java:1884) at
  com.sleepycat.je.Database.openCursor(Database.java:676) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.berkeleyje.BerkeleyJEKeyValueStore.getSlice(BerkeleyJEKeyValueStore.java:119)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at com.sleepycat.je.log.LogUtils.readBytesNoLength(LogUtils.java:365) at
  com.sleepycat.je.log.entry.LNLogEntry.readBaseLNEntry(LNLogEntry.java:205) at
  com.sleepycat.je.log.entry.LNLogEntry.readEntry(LNLogEntry.java:130) at
  com.sleepycat.je.log.LogManager.getLogEntryFromLogSource(LogManager.java:1008) at com.sleepycat.je.log.LogManager.getLogEntry(LogManager.java:848) at
  com.sleepycat.je.log.LogManager.getLogEntryAllowInvisibleAtRecovery(LogManager.java:809) at com.sleepycat.je.tree.IN.fetchTarget(IN.java:1412) at
  com.sleepycat.je.tree.BIN.fetchTarget(BIN.java:1251) at
  com.sleepycat.je.dbi.CursorImpl.fetchCurrent(CursorImpl.java:2261) at
  com.sleepycat.je.dbi.CursorImpl.getCurrentAlreadyLatched(CursorImpl.java:1466) at com.sleepycat.je.dbi.CursorImpl.getNext(CursorImpl.java:1593) at
  com.sleepycat.je.Cursor.retrieveNextAllowPhantoms(Cursor.java:2924) at com.sleepycat.je.Cursor.retrieveNextNoDups(Cursor.java:2801) at
  com.sleepycat.je.Cursor.retrieveNext(Cursor.java:2775) at
  com.sleepycat.je.Cursor.getNext(Cursor.java:1128) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.berkeleyje.BerkeleyJEKeyValueStore.getSlice(BerkeleyJEKeyValueStore.java:135) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.keyvalue.OrderedKeyValueStoreAdapter.getSlice(OrderedKeyValueStoreAdapter.java:63) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.CachedKeyColumnValueStore.getSlice(CachedKeyColumnValueStore.java:105) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.BackendTransaction$1.call(BackendTransaction.java:181) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.BackendTransaction$1.call(BackendTransaction.java:178) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:62) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.executeRead(BackendTransaction.java:380) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.BackendTransaction.edgeStoreQuery(BackendTransaction.java:178) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.cache.PassThroughStoreCache.query(PassThroughStoreCache.java:19) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.edgeQuery(StandardTitanGraph.java:209) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.query.SimpleVertexQueryProcessor$6.get(SimpleVertexQueryProcessor.java:179) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.query.SimpleVertexQueryProcessor$6.get(SimpleVertexQueryProcessor.java:176) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.vertices.CacheVertex.loadRelations(CacheVertex.java:39) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.query.SimpleVertexQueryProcessor.getBasicIterator(SimpleVertexQueryProcessor.java:176) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.query.SimpleVertexQueryProcessor.iterator(SimpleVertexQueryProcessor.java:105) at com.google.common.collect.Iterables$8.iterator(Iterables.java:713) at
  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.util.VertexCentricEdgeIterable$EdgeIterator.getNextEdge(VertexCentricEdgeIterable.
```

So I am not able to count the number of edges accurately. Is there an alternate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an error.  It is a warning.  If your graph is small enough to be able to iterate `E` then feel free to do so.  Sometimes that message is welcome as it reminds you that you are doing something possibly crazy.  You should be able to tune the log level to get rid of that message.

Comment: Hi Stephen, the command stops with a "permanent exception" and no value for the count is returned at the end.

Comment: Please include the stack trace in your question.

Comment: Note that the exception shows that you have heapspace problems: " more Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space".  You should allocate some more `Xmx` to get through the iteration.